# String literal is not properly closed error for backslash

Tags: java

Here is part of my code

```
OutputStream os;
    if (isWin){
        os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "\" + destinationFile);
    }
    else{
        os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + destinationFile);
    }
```

I got the "string literal is not properly closed by double quote error" at the backslash line. if I remove the backslash or change it to forward slash, the error will disappear.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The backslash in java opens for a special character like `\n` (newline). If you write two doubleslashed `\\\` you will escape the backslash and make the String notify that no special character is placed at this position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is better to use `File` api for separators, so you have not to check what OS it is:

```
os = new FileOutputStream(folder + File.separatorChar + destinationFile);
```

Comment: Wow. I've been writing in Java for quite some time now, I never even realised this was available. Thanks.

Comment: I will probably forget it come time to use it, probably have done this entire conversation before. Such is my relationship with programming.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
"\\"
```

instead of:

```
"\"
```

in:

```
os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "\" + destinationFile);
```

Otherwise you are backslashing the `"` character.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `File.separator` instead of `\` and `/`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to solve:

```
    // Fix the '\'
    if (isWin) {
        os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "\\" + destinationFile);
    } else {
        os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + destinationFile);
    }
    // Avoid using path separator
    os = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder, destinationFile));
    // OS agnostic
    os = new FileOutputStream(folder + File.separator + destinationFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` is a symbol that is part of the compilation process (has many uses in Java) and hence must be escaped if seeking it's literal value. Coincidentally, `\` is also the escape sequence character.

The final solution to use a real `\` (backslash) in your code is to escape it, i.e. `"\\"` will output `\`.

```
os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "\\" + destinationFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` as `\\`.

```
os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "\\" + destinationFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put `\` and `/` into this string.
Problem is there - while you use `\"` in string, that will print `"` character, you need to "escape" character which you need- in this case you need to escape `\`, so you have the solution there

```
 os = new FileOutputStream(folder + "\" + destinationFile);
```

Btw try it paste into system.out and you will see :)

- " \n "  - new line
- " \t "  - tab
- " " " error
- " \" " - print `"`
- " ' " - print `'`
- " \ " - print `\`

:o)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid slash and backslash:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(new File(folder ), destinationFile));
```